# Laravel 5.5 and angular 4 integration

Tags: php, jquery, angular, typescript, laravel-5.5

I am working on a ERP system that is 6 years old and it is developed in raw PHP maintaining procedural coding structure without OOP or any Framework.

Finally our management decided to re-write the application with upgraded technologies. We will write the application in Laravel Framework. Database will be Oracle and Mysql both. In the front end we will use Angular 4.

The confusion is should i use Angular 4 for front end request handling and data binding? Or i should go with Javascript/Jquery. Last few days i am seeking some suggestions on the net. I found some also. My question is, how should i integrate Laravel and angular? should i go for API based approach maintaining two different project for Laravel and Angular or angular inside Laravel in a folder? If i go for API based approach, will my ajax request increased? The database of the application will be too large.
will API based approach make data loading slower?

All the request in the application will be ajax based and there will be no page refresh approach, but url will change on request.

Please suggest me the possible right solution to help me taking the right decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular 2/4+ has been designed to build SPA (Single Page Application). If you deep dive into angular then it will be clear to you that all the structures and conventions followed in the angular 2+ architecture are optimized for SPA.

So, if you want to use Angular with Laravel 5+ then I think the best way would be to use angular to build a standalone frontend application and use Laravel 5+ as a backend. That means laravel will act as an API server and a backend of the application.

Using laravel as an API server doesn't necessarily mean your database will be bigger. It is actually upto you how you design your application.

But, there is an another good solution.
You can use [VueJs](https://github.com/vuejs/vue). There is a build in support for VueJs within Laravel 5+. 
The benefit of using VueJs is that you can use it just like Jquery. That means you don't have to create separate standalone application for VueJs like Angular.
But, you can use it, page by page basis. It is loosely coupled. 
You will get most of the benefit of Angular from it.

You can also use React.

Comment: Does an ERP should be design in SPA? Yes, i am already thinking about using Vue/React.

Comment: Of course, ERP can be design in SPA. It is very feasible and realistic. You know, all depends on how you design it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Angular 4** to rewrite your application. Fontend as **Single Page Application** and Backend exposing **REST API** will help you to build a good performance application.

I prefer to keep **Angular** and **REST API** separate as they should be independent to each other. **REST API**s should always be generic so that they can be consumed by other applications too.

Yes, there will be lot of API calls to server. You can scale your **REST API**s according to your number of requests. It is better building **micro-services** to ensure most of the services will not be impacted in case of lot of heavy load *(at least part of application will be running)*. It will help you in future maintenance also.